# Failed to apply plugin [class 'JetGradlePlugin'] Problem with setting up 1.8 Minecraft modding workspace in IntelliJ

Tags: minecraft-forge

Disclaimer I've already fixed the problem, this is just for others that might have the same issue as I couldn't find a fix anywhere else.

The stack trace error was:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [class 'JetGradlePlugin']

Look at my answer below for how I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file

Change

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.7-bin.zip
```

to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip
```

Then reload the Gradle changes with the little Elephant button with a blue arrow circle.

Now it should build properly without that error.